# close the fullscreen menu overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery

My fullscreen menu overlay has a close button but I'd like to close the overlay also by clicking on the overlay itself. So if you click outside the menu on the overlay the overlay closes. The same as the close btw does.
Her's the code but what to add or edit.

```
(function() {
    var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' ),
        overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
        closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
            'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition': 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

    function toggleOverlay() {
        if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
            classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
            classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
            var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support.transitions ) {
                    if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                }
                classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
            };
            if( support.transitions ) {
                overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            else {
                onEndTransitionFn();
            }
        }
        else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
            classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
        }
    }

    triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
    closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is put an event listener for 'click' on the entire overlay div.

```
overlay.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
```

At the bottom

Answer (score 0):

closeBttn wasn't really defined because there were no "button" at all (only "a" tags).

Code:

```
(function() {
var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' );
var overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' );
var closeBttn = document.querySelector( '#smp_menu' );
    transEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
        'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
        'transition': 'transitionend'
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
    support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

function toggleOverlay() {
    if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
        classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
        classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
        var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
            if( support.transitions ) {
                if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
        };
        if( support.transitions ) {
            overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
        }
        else {
            onEndTransitionFn();
        }
    }
    else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
        classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
    }
}

triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay);
})();
```

This will define the "closeBttn" (wich was not used) as the whole overlay area.

So, this is needed on script.js to change the class of the button when it's not clicked right below the current code:

```
var otherthingy = document.querySelector('#smp_menu');
otherthingy.addEventListener('click', function (){
    button.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

Comment: That's beyond me I'm afraid. maybe you can do browser inspect element to see what's wrong. the page is http://exp.testpress.nl

Comment: Ok, so it's a wordpress with revslider. Some JS code are messed up. The easies way would be to add a custom script tag with `document.getElementById("smp_menu").addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );`  EDIT: Mixed jquery with js lol

Comment: added below the script: document.getElementById("smp_menu").addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );  but nada doesn't work

Comment: If you can edit that file, then end every line with a ";" at the beggining `var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' ),
  overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
  closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );` should be `var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' );
   var overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' );
  var closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );` because it's giving a "Cannot read property of null" when trying to access `closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );`

Comment: can you fix the script and paste it here for me please I'm a complete noop at js and I don't want to mess it up.

Comment: now it closed the overlay but it doesn't undo the icon animation as i can see

Comment: yes it's working! thank you so very much. The best thing is that I understand what you did. wow I learned something today. You'r the man :)

Comment: one thing I noticed is that the icon is not returning to hamburger after closing the menu when you click on the overlay OEPS!

Comment: Can Lord Neo fix that :)

Comment: Edited again, i just redirected the closeBttn to trigger the triggerBttn, so it should do the whole remove class thingy (both events do the same call).

Comment: try with this: `closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', triggerBttn.toggleOverlay);`

Comment: back to where we started now :)

Comment: I admire your patience :)

Comment: reverted to functional code and added the extra thing on script.js to toggle the icon too. that should be it xD

Comment: I knew you would fix it. You are the new Rambo of coding. Thanx for helping me out.